# A sufficient condition for a relaxation of Lipschitz continuity

Tags: calculus, metric-spaces, lipschitz-functions

I am interested in a property that, I believe, is closely related to Lipschitz continuity. Lipschitz continuity is defined as:

> Given two metric spaces $(X, d_X)$ and $(Y, d_Y)$, where $d_X$ denotes the
> metric on the set $X$ and $d_Y$ is the metric on set $Y$, a function $f: X\rightarrow Y$ is called Lipschitz continuous if there exists a real constant $K \geq 0$
> such that, for all $x_1$ and $x_2$ in $X$,
> $d_{Y}(f(x_{1}),f(x_{2}))\leq Kd_{X}(x_{1},x_{2}).$

I focus on the case $K=1$ in which case $f$ is called a [metric map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_map) and I take this relaxation:

> $d_{Y}(f(x_{1}),f(x_{2}))\leq d_{X}(x_{1},x_{2}) + \varepsilon$

for a $\varepsilon \geq 0$.

I am interested in the condition:

$D_{X,Y}(x, f(x)) \leq \varepsilon$, for $D$ a metric between spaces $X$ and $Y$ and $\varepsilon\geq 0$. I'm assuming that the metric $D$ exists, for example, when $X=Y$.

That is, we are limiting where $f$ can send $x$.

I believe that this property would imply my relaxation of Lipschitz. For example, if we assume $d = D = d_Y = d_Y$, by the triangle inequality:

$d(f(x_{1}),f(x_{2}))\leq d(f(x_{1}), x_1) + d(x_2,f(x_{2})) + d(x_2,x_1)\leq 2\,\varepsilon + d(x_2,x_1).$

I am trying to find more information related to this.

Comment: Can you please tell the meaning of relaxation here? I am not so good at english

Comment: Yes, the condition is $d_{Y}(f(x_{1}),f(x_{2}))\leq d_{X}(x_{1},x_{2})$. By relaxation I mean adding some slack to the condition so that it is not as "hard" to satisfy. Instead of requiring the exact condition, I require $d_{Y}(f(x_{1}),f(x_{2}))\leq d_{X}(x_{1},x_{2}) + \varepsilon$, for some $\varepsilon\geq 0$ (the slack variable).